# Mail Merge Macro

Tags: mailmerge

I have looked through the recommendations for doing MailMerge with a macro. I just need to be pushed in the right direction. Before I started working on the MailMerge aspect, I did get the macro to open the word file (docx) then save under a new name using the Excel sheet 1 project info that was inputed. I am running the macro from the source document so I don't know if that is an issue with the vba. I get it to open the word file but it asks me if sheet 1 is OK (source file). Thanks for any help or direction you may be able to give

Sub OpenDocFileNewName()
'
' OpenDocFileNewName Macro
'
'

```
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application.8")

Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\mmezzolesta\Documents\_TestDataMerge\STANDARD.docx")

WordApp.Visible = True

'
'mail merge
'

Data = "C:\Users\mmezzolesta\Documents\_TestDataMerge\test_table.xlsm"

' WordDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource (Data)
```

WordDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Filename:=Data, SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"

```
'Sheets("Sheet1").Select

WordMailMerge.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=("C:\Users\mmezzolesta\Documents\_TestMailMergeAuto") & "/" & Range("A2") & "Standard-Grounding-" & Range("e2").Text

WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close

WordApp.Quit
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you need in recent versions of Word (which use OLE DB to connect by default) is:

```
WordDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Filename:=Data, _
SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
```

then you perform the merge using

```
WordDoc.MailMerge.Execute
```

and if you are merging to a new document, the output will typically become the ActiveDocument.

You shouldn't need this for the merge...

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```

Comment: Sub OpenDocFileNewName()

Comment: Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application.8")
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\mmezzolesta\Documents\_TestDataMerge\STANDARD.docx")
WordApp.Visible = TrueData = "C:\Users\mmezzolesta\Documents\_TestDataMerge\test_table.xlsm"
WordDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Filename:=Data, SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
WordDoc.MailMerge.ExecuteWordMailMerge.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=("C:\Users\mmezzolesta\Documents\_TestMailMergeAuto") & "/" & Range("A2") & "Standard-Grounding-" & Range("e2").Text
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close
    WordApp.Quit

Comment: Hi Bibadiak, I changed the line of text to WordDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Filename:= Data, SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]" and still get the debug to stop on this line. Did I leave too many spaces or used the wrong symbols?

Comment: Works OK here with Word 2010, but I am assuming that your sheet is actually called "Sheet1". (I wondered whether using the reserved word "Data" might cause a problem - it doesn't appear to, but it might be better to give your variable a different name). 

Can you connect to the data source manually?

Answer (score 0):

still having a bit of trouble with the Select Table. When I run the Macro, the Select Table box pops up and I have to say "OK" even though there is only one sheet in the Excel file. The original Word document will not close until I click the "Save" button. Is there an easy way around this to automate in vba?

The updated code is

Sub OpenDocFileNewName()
'
' OpenDocFileNewName Macro
'
'

```
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application.8")

Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\mmezzolesta\Documents\_TestDataMerge\STANDARD.docx")

WordApp.Visible = True

'
'mail merge
'

Data = "C:\Users\mmezzolesta\Documents\_TestDataMerge\test_table.xlsm"

WordDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource (Data)

WordDoc.MailMerge.Execute

'
'Sheets("Sheet1").Select

WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=("C:\Users\mmezzolesta\Documents\_TestMailMergeAuto") & "/" & Range("A2") & "Standard-Grounding-" & Range("e2").Text

WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close

WordApp.Quit
```

End Sub
    '